# Vanity URL's for Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, routes

I want to add vanity URL's to a model in my application. Ideally, I'd like it to fallback to ID's if a user doesn't have a username. Here's the current solution I've built, but it isn't working.

User.rb

```
  def to_param
     username || id
  end
```

User Controller

```
@user = if params.key?(:username)
    User.find_by_name(params[:username])
else
    User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Routes

```
match "/:username" => "users#show", via: :get
```

Comment: Use friendly_id gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: `find_by_x` methods have been deprecated for some time, you should be using `where(username: params[:username]).first`

Comment: Might be useful if you explained what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your route generates a username param regardless of whether or not it's actually a username or an ID that you pass in. Therefore, in your controller you shouldn't be trying to use `params[:id]`. Other than that, I can see nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:--

```
get ':id', to: 'users#show', constraints: lambda { |request| User.where(:username => request.path_parameters[:id]).exists? }
```

User Controller

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
unless @user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```